# Forms Authentication for any type of file along with .aspx file

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, iis-7.5

I have a website set for forms Authentication + anonymous access.

When user requests for any page ( managed resource such as .aspx page) then he gets redirected to Logon.aspx

Problem appears in case of resources which are unmanaged such as .html , .png , .jpg etc files.
When user tries to access such resources directly by using URL, he is able to view these resources without any authentication.
He is not redirected to LogOn.aspx page.

I tried following:

**Edit Managed Module for DefaultAuthentication and FormsAuthentication by changing settings in IIS 7.5 by changin settings in Modules.

When I uncheck "Invoke only for requests to ASP.NET applications or managed handlers" check box and save, I am getting a warning message as displayed below.

"The specified type cannot be found among the referenced assemblies for this application. Make sure that the assembly is added to the list of assemblies in the system.web/compilation section of web.config  of this application. Do you still want to continue?"

I have read on a blog that we can ignore this warning message and, click "Yes" option in warning message to save the settings.

After saving the change, this addes following lines in Web.config :

```
<remove name="DefaultAuthentication" />
        <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
<add name="FormsAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
  <add name="DefaultAuthentication" type="System.Web.Security.DefaultAuthenticationModule" preCondition="" />
```

After these changes user is still able to view unmanaged resources without any authentication.

Is there anything I am missing here? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can force the web server to run all managed modules (including the forms module) for your static files by setting the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests to true in the modules section of the system.webServer section if the web.config.

The drawback is that running modules for static data slows your server down, however you will certainly get the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried this too but there is no effect of this change in bahaviour of the site.